# How do I edit values in a web-browser. .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, vb.net, browser

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_cphBanner_BannerAlertsLoginView_BannerAlerts_Authenticated_rbxBanner​Alert_rbxAlerts_RobuxAlertCaptionHyperLink" class="RobuxAlertCaption tooltip-bottom" href="AccountBalance.aspx" original-title="ROBUX">740</a>
```

How do I edit the 740. For example, If button1 is pressed then. 740 textbox1.text.
How do I edit the webbrowser HTML with the text box value

Comment: I see no textbox in your code - are you talking about a Windows Forms textbox? Please post more code.

Comment: I believe you are having a hard time understanding what I meant. I want to edit a HTML tag in visual-basic " I want to edit this HTML line from the vb program. original-title="ROBUX"> The value I want to replace which would be 720</a> So, I basically want the program to edit the value 720 and replace it with the txtbox value inside of my vb program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JQUERY

```
$("#<%= txtName.ClientID%>").val("Test");
```

Comment: I believe you are having a hard time understanding what I meant. I want to edit a HTML tag in visual-basic " I want to edit this HTML line from the vb program. original-title="ROBUX"> The value I want to replace which would be 720</a> So, I basically want the program to edit the value 720 and replace it with the txtbox value inside of my vb program

Answer (score 0):

If if you want to do it after postback, There is a few solution

**Make your tag as .net registered;**

> `<a id="hrefReplace" runat="server"></a>`

And change attribute like

> hrefReplace.Width = 775;

Post a Javascript to your App

> `string jScript;
>       jScriptValidator="<script> $("#<%= txtName.ClientID%>").widht(775);)";
>       Page.RegisterStartupScript("regJSval",jScriptValidator);`